# Sine-Gordon equation: kink and antikink

Tags: partial-differential-equations, soliton-theory

I am considering the sine-Gordon equation $u_{xt}=\sin u$. It is well known that it has 1-soliton solutions, known as *kinks* and *antikinks*.

How exactly are they defined?

As far as I know, a kink is a solution of the form
$$
u(x,t)=-4\arctan(\exp(\lambda x+\frac{t}{\lambda}+\mu))=4\arctan(C\exp(\lambda x+\frac{t}{\lambda})),\quad C:=-\exp(\mu),\quad \lambda>0\tag{1}
$$
while an antikink is a solution of the form
$$
u(x,t)=-4\arctan(\exp(\lambda x+\frac{t}{\lambda}+\mu))=4\arctan(C\exp(\lambda x+\frac{t}{\lambda})),\quad C:=-\exp(\mu),\quad \lambda<0.\tag{2}
$$

If I am not mistaken, solution (1) is decreasing, while (2) is increasing.

That's a little bit confusing because in the literature, a kink usually seems to be identified with the 1-soliton solution with $\lambda>0$ but increasing, while an antikink is usually the 1-soliton with $\lambda<0$ but decreasing.

Comment: Does it really matter? Changing variables $u \mapsto -u$ results in the same equation, but the two solutions are swapped. Probably it is fine as long as *one of them* is the kink, and the other antikink.

Comment: I am just asking, because it is asked what conditions are need for the 2-soliton solution $$u(x,t)=4\arctan\left[\left(\frac{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}\right)\tan\left(\frac{v_1-v_2}{4}\right)\right]$$ in order to have kink-kink interaction. For this, I need to know what is the definition of a kink, because I think that $v_1$ and $v_2$ are needed to be both kinks in order to have kink-kink interaction.

Comment: It might be that different authors have different definitions. And if it is really the case you just have to live with it.

Comment: But am I right that (1), as defined above, is decreasing, while (2) is increasing?